# Stuck on terminal

Tags: 16.04

I was on this site http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/05/install-gnome-3-20-ubuntu-16-04-lts attempting to download Gnome.  However, when I restarted I was left with the terminal blinking 3 times and I was booted directly into terminal and it ws covering both of my screens. Usually, I have a dual screen for mroe space, but this was both screens on the same terminal session. There is no sign of the GUI here. I have tried the ctl+alt+f7 or f1-6 and it's the terminal again. Any idea how I can go back to my regular 16.0.4 LTS GUI again?

Comment: Screenshot or photo please

Answer (score 1):

Since you have access to the terminal, it is good. You can reinstall GNOME with these two commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
sudo service gdm restart
```

Comment: Maybe he can try enabling the desktop service for Gnome and then he can know it is actually broken